# WPF handling text, image and file pasting event

Tags: wpf

I'm developing a WPF application, and I'd like to catch the paste command in a RichTextBox input and handle the pasted files. For this I'm using the following callback:

```
<RichTextBox DataObject.Pasting="BodyRichTextBox_Pasting">
```

```
private void BodyRichTextBox_Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e) {
    // handler 1
}
```

I can handle the text and image pasting, but when I'd like to paste files, then this callback doesn't get fired.

I also can catch the paste event with:

```
<RichTextBox.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />
</RichTextBox.CommandBindings>
```

```
private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
  // handler 2
}
```

But this callback overrides the previous one, and I need important fields from the `DataObjectPastingEventArgs` variable. So I wanted to use the first handler to handle text and image pasting and the second for file pasting, but doesn't works both together (If I set `e.Handled` to `false` doesn't help).

Any other idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the `ApplicationCommands.Paste` command something like this to get the pasted in text, file(s) or image:

```
private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Paste)
    {
        var files = Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
        var text = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
        var image = Clipboard.GetImage();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```